# CSS Some classes not applying

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a class that I can apply to text elements to change their color based on a variable. When I inline it, it works, but when I try to create a custom class in my styles, it doesn't work. Yet, one of my custom classes does work, which makes it even more confusing.

Here's the particular html snippet in question:

```css
/* Set initial variable values here */
:root {
    --button-color: #00FFFF;
}

/* Allow colors to be overwritten here */
.text-color {
    color: var(--button-color);
}

.border-color {
    border-width: 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #00FFFF;
}

.clickable {
    background-image: url('../patterns/debut_dark.png');
}
```

```html
<h3 class='clickable text-center py-2 mb-2 rounded shadow text-color border-color'>Hello</h4>
```

clickable is a custom class, it works.
The others, up to text-color are bootstrap classes. They work.
text-color and border-color are my other custom classes defined in the same file where clickable is defined.

I can't figure out why the class declarations don't work but inlining

```
<h3 class='clickable text-center py-2 mb-2 rounded shadow text-color border-color' style="color: var(--button-color);">Hello</h4>
```

does work.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you inspect the styles in your browsers developer console, is it being overwritten by a higher priority style?

Comment: As you can see from the snippet, your code works, therefore you have a style overriding the above.  As dbs says, you can inspect the element to see which that style is and then create a more specific rule to override it. Also just so you know - you have an h4 closing your h3

Comment: Your code is working just fine to me... could you please post your CSS file so we can tell you what's overriding your code and preventing you from changing the color in your way. 

because I don't want to recommend ID `#` or `!important` they will ruin the CSS specificity and I don't want you to use either of them to fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think the issue might be a caching one.
It seems that, after pushing my changes to github (even though I'm using localhost and not github to see the changes) and waiting like 20 minutes, booting it back up applied the changes.

Comment: stylesheets are cached locally - if you make changes then use ctrl f5 to do a "hard refresh" which will make the browser pull everything down again

Answer (score -1):

maybe just a workarount hth..

```
/* Allow colors to be overwritten here */
.text-color {
    color: var(--button-color) !important;
}
```

Just for debugging :-)

Comment: not a good solution use important, better to find why and what css overwrite that rule

Comment: If this doesn't work the problem is not here... it's a solution for faster debugging...

Comment: It was just a suggestion for debugging